Update ADF trigger time for week days (Monday to Saturday) using azure PowerShell script
I wrote the following PowerShell script, but encountered an issue while setting weekdays from Monday to Saturday. The error I received was:
##[error]Exception setting "WeekDays": "Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Collections.Generic.IList1[System.Nullable1[Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory.Models.DaysOfWeek]]"."

I attempted to set up the weekdays in two different ways:
First approach:
$trigger.Properties.Recurrence.Schedule = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory.Models.RecurrenceSchedule
$trigger.Properties.Recurrence.Schedule.WeekDays = @("Friday", "Saturday")

Second approach, in the following code:
$adf_name = $env:Adf_Name
$resourcegroup_name = $env:ResourceGroup_Name

$blobContainerName = $env:blobContainerName
$StorageAccountName = $env:StorageAccountName

Write-Host "ADF Name: $adf_name"
Write-Host "Resource Group: $resourcegroup_name"
Write-Host "Blob Container Name: $blobContainerName"
Write-Host "Storage Account Name: $StorageAccountName"

$triggerName = "Dwh_Business_Days_MTD_Data_Load"
Write-Host "Trigger Name: $triggerName"

$timeZone = "Eastern Standard Time"  # Set to Eastern Standard Time (EST)
$startTime = [datetime]::ParseExact("04:40:00", "HH:mm:ss", $null)  # Set trigger time

# Step 3: Get the trigger
$trigger = Get-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup_name -DataFactoryName $adf_name -Name $triggerName

Write-Host ($trigger.Properties | Format-List -Property * | Out-String)

# Step 4: Define the recurrence schedule
$trigger.Properties.Recurrence = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory.Models.ScheduleTriggerRecurrence
$trigger.Properties.Recurrence.Frequency = "Week"
$trigger.Properties.Recurrence.Interval = 1
$trigger.Properties.Recurrence.StartTime = $startTime
$trigger.Properties.Recurrence.TimeZone = $timeZone
$trigger.Properties.Recurrence.Schedule = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory.Models.RecurrenceSchedule
$trigger.Properties.Recurrence.Schedule.WeekDays = [Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory.Models.DaysOfWeek]::Friday, `
                                    [Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory.Models.DaysOfWeek]::Saturday
$trigger.Properties.Recurrence.Schedule.Hours = @(4)  # 4 AM EST
$trigger.Properties.Recurrence.Schedule.Minutes = @(40)  # 40 minutes

# Step 5: Update the trigger in ADF
Set-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup_name -DataFactoryName $adf_name -Name $triggerName -Definition $trigger.Properties -Force

What should I try next to correctly set the weekdays from Monday to Saturday?
According to Microsoft documentation, triggers can be created or updated using the Set-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger PowerShell command. However, I keep getting the following error:
##[error]Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory.Models.ScheduleTrigger

This happens even when no changes are made to the trigger. I have also tried other methods to update the trigger time properties, but none have worked so far.

why don't you use ADF itself to trigger pipeline on weekdays?

@bhavani we have 3 environment dev, qa & prod, once any changes made to adf triggers time updated with dev setting using arm template via CI CD but we need different time for triggers in prod environment, currently we made changes to trigger time manually in prod need to automate

You can use the below PowerShell script to ADF trigger time for weekdays (Monday to Saturday):
az datafactory trigger update --factory-name "<adfName>" --resource-group "<resourceGroupName>" --name "<triggerNmae>" --set properties.recurrence.schedule.weekDays='["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]' --set properties.recurrence.schedule.hours='[9, 15]' --set properties.recurrence.schedule.minutes='[30, 0]'

It will update the trigger time for weekdays as shown below:

